# Bounding $|g(x)|$ to prove product rule for limits

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

There's a small detail I'm still not convinced I understood well. My work from the beginning to the point I got stuck is the following.

Let $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = M$

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)g(x)] = LM \space \space so \space\space \forall \varepsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0 \space\space s.t \space\space 0 \lt |x-a| \lt \delta \implies |f(x)g(x) - LM| \lt \varepsilon \end{align}

Working with $\varepsilon$ inequality:

\begin{align}
\|f(x)g(x) + L \cdot g(x) - L \cdot g(x) - LM| \\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
& = \|g(x)[f(x) - L] + L[g(x) - M]| \\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
& \le \|g(x)[f(x) - L]| + |L[g(x) - M]| \\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
& = |g(x)||f(x) - L| + |L||g(x) - M| \lt \varepsilon.
\end{align}

But we need $|g(x)||f(x) - L|$ and $|L||g(x) - M|$ to be both less than $\frac {\varepsilon}2$, so:

$|L||g(x) - M| \lt \frac {\varepsilon}2 \implies |g(x) - M| \lt \frac {\varepsilon}{2 \cdot |L|}$. To avoid the possibility of having division by $0$ when $L = 0$, add $1$ to $|L|$ term to make the demominator greater than $0$.
Thus $|g(x) - M| \lt \frac {\varepsilon}{2 \cdot (1 + |L|)}$.

Since $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = M$, there exists $\delta_1 \gt 0$ $\space$ such that $\space$ $0 \lt |x - a| < \delta_1 \implies |g(x) - L| \lt \frac {\varepsilon}{2 \cdot (1 + |L|)}$. There will also exist $\delta_2 \gt 0 \space$ such that $\space$ $|g(x)||f(x) - L| \lt \frac {\varepsilon}{2}$ as $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$.

This point is where I am a bit confused. We need to bound $|g(x)|$ in order to avoid dealing with variables just as $x$, but in many resources I read, they just set $|g(x) - M| \lt 1$ to finally get $|g(x)| \lt 1 + |M|$. As far as I know, that happens because we set $\varepsilon = 1$ now, but won't that restrict the rule for certain values of $\varepsilon$? How does this work?

Comment: Make $|f(x)-L|<\frac {\epsilon} 2({1+|M|)}$.

Comment: But how do get $1 + |M|$ first? That's my doubt, I don't understand how we can say that $|g(x) - M| \lt 1$.

Comment: Choose your $\delta_1$ with the **additional** condition $|g(x)-M|<1$ for $0< |x-a|<\delta_1$.

Comment: I mean, we take $\delta =$ min{$\delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_3$} at the end, so that implies $|g(x) - M| \lt 1$, so $\varepsilon$ will be restricted for this case, that's not a problem?

Answer (score 1):

By $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ what we really care about are the arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$, so their argument considering $|g(x)-M|<1$ holds. Continuity is all about how functions get bounded more and more for smaller $\varepsilon$ so discarding the large $\varepsilon$ that bound $g$ poorly doesn't matter.

You also don't have to worry too much about the $L=0$ case because if it arises then you'll want to show $|f(x)g(x)|<\varepsilon \ \Leftrightarrow \ |f(x)||g(x)|<\varepsilon$. This is the same problem because $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to a$ and you want $g$ to be bounded.

Comment: So taking $\varepsilon = 1$ is enough to prove the rule? Larger values won't matter?

Comment: Yes, but observe that any $\varepsilon>0$ would be sufficient, like $\varepsilon=1/2$ or $\varepsilon=17$.

Comment: Oh, so it works just like $\delta$ in those quadratic limits, for example? We can take a $\varepsilon$ as big/small as we want? Also, that's how the proof works? We take $\varepsilon = 1$, but we can prove that also for $1, 1/2, 17$ or any other number will also be useful to do it?

Comment: Exactly! All we care about above, when $\varepsilon=1$, is $|g(x)||f(x)-L| < |1+|M|||f(x)-L|$ which we can get arbitrarily small. What value the constant 1+|M| takes isn't important.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way is to apply $$f(x)g(x)-LM=[f(x)-L][g(x)-M]+M[f(x)-L]+L[g(x)-M]$$ Fix $0<\eta<1.$ If $|f(x)-L|\le \eta$ and $|g(x)-M|\le \eta$ then $$|f(x)g(x)-LM|\le \eta^2+|M|\eta+|L|\eta \\ <\eta(1+|L|+|M|)$$ For given $\varepsilon>0$ take $$\eta={\varepsilon\over \varepsilon +1+|L|+|M|}$$ and choose an appropriate $\delta>0$ so that $|f(x)-L|\le \eta$ and $|g(x)-M|\le \eta$ for $0<|x-a|<\delta.$

Comment: $|f(x)g(x) - LM|$ needs to be less than $\varepsilon$, so we need to set $\eta$ to cancel out $(1 + |L| + |M|)$, why would we write another $\varepsilon$ in the denominator?

Comment: It cancels $1+|L|+|M|$ and is less than $1.$ That's why $\varepsilon$ shows up in the denominator.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I still don't get how.

Comment: I have used in the proof that $0<\eta\le 1.$ So we need that $\eta\le {\varepsilon \over 1+|L|+|M|}.$ Observe that  $\eta ={\varepsilon \over \varepsilon+1+|L|+|M|}$ satisfies both requirements.